# Polymer doesn't allow to style inner elements and propagate events in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, polymer, dom-events

I've started using Polymer in these weeks. I'm attempting to create a `paper-submit` element which includes a button and a `paper-button`, which, once pressed, triggers a hidden button's click event.

This works fine in Firefox: the `paper-button` gets styled correctly (using a class) and the click event triggers the button's click event and the containing form triggers the submit one.

**On Chrome though, the paper-button ignores the style I've set (see example: no background color change) and it seems to stop propagating the button's click event. The result is an unstyled paper-button which triggers nothing.**

This is the source:

CSS style, linked in the main page:

```
paper-button.blue {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #2196F3; }
```

paper-submit polymer element:

```
<link href="../polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="../paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<polymer-element name="paper-submit" attributes="bClass raised recenteringTouch fill" role="button">
  <template>
    <style>
      #submit-button {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-button id="button" class="{{bClass}}" raised="{{raised}}" recenteringTouch="{{recenteringTouch}}" role="button">
      <content></content>
    </paper-button>

    <button type="submit" id="submit-button"></button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      publish: {
        bClass: '',
        raised: false,
        recenteringTouch: false,
        fill: true
      },

      ready: function () {
        var submit = this.$['submit-button'];
        var button = this.$.button;
        button.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
          submit.click();
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Note: I've tried inserting a simple button inside the `paper-input` element to test if it was something related to the JavaScript's click function, but it's not: same result.

This is how I call the element:

```
<paper-submit bClass="blue" role="button" tabindex="0">Click me!</paper-submit>
```

The element is inside a form with some mandatory fields: on Firefox they trigger the error, on Chrome nothing happens.

May you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach: [Declarative event mapping](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping)

```
<paper-button id="button" on-click="{{click_submit}}" ...

  click_submit: function () {
    var submit = this.$['submit-button'];
      submit.click();
  }
```

Comment: Hello Goce, thanks for the suggestion. Though, even if it cleans my code, this doesn't help me out sorting my main problem.

Comment: paper-button doesn't fire 'click' event, so you can't add listener for it.
Check the docs and look at the demo source code: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-button.html

Comment: Hello Goce. This is the reason why I've created the custom element: it includes a hidden submit button which should trigger the outer form's submit event. As written in the question, this works in Firefox, but it doesn't in Chrome. Also, the style is ignored (it correctly binds the argument value to the paper-button class' one, but the style is ignored, see question).

Answer (score 1):

As far as the css goes, if you are outside the shadow boundaries, you need to pierce them to override them...

```
body /deep/ paper-button {
  ...
}
```

Here is a codepen with [an example](http://codepen.io/Nevraeka/pen/bNJLLr?editors=100)

Not sure why you have to use a new element in this case despite what you said in the comments. You should be able to do the styling & form submit either way. I probably just don't have context on your project so I apologize if I am not correct in this.

For some inspiration using 'paper forms' also check out [paper-form-on-fire](https://github.com/HackITtoday/paper-form-on-fire)

Comment: Thanks Erik, this resolves my style problem. About the submit issue: the `button` is just ignored... I'd like to avoid using an entire plugin which uses 3rd-party systems (Firebase by Google in this case) just to submit a form... makes sense, no? - This is my project: http://crm.giacomofurlan.name/login - as you can see, Chrome doesn't react to the button's click event.

Comment: I've tried searching for the host's closest form and submit it - and it works - but it will completely bypass the HTML5's validation.

Comment: I've come to a solution, which though is a workaround and I don't feel it like a real solution: I find the closest form, inject a `button` with `type="submit"`, click on it and then I remove it from the DOM. See https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1361 for the code.